# why is job applying as many TMs as default parallelism when starting

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, flink-streaming

If I set TM number=6, slot num each TM=8, memory each TM=4G, the job will apply 48 TMs, and use only one slot each, total memory usage is 192G. A few minutes later, it will release 40TMs, everything will be normal.

Is there any reason about it?

Answer (score 0):

Since Flink 1.5, having taskmanagers with multiple slots is not supported on Yarn (using the default runtime mode). See the [release notes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/release-notes/flink-1.5.html#update-configuration-for-reworked-job-deployment) for more details.

You can still use Flink with the legacy runtime by configuring `mode: legacy`.

Comment: hi, David Anderson, it's not supported during start period or the whole streaming process? Because I found it will use 8*6 instead of 48*1 a few minutes later.